# ToggleButtons in JavaFX with generic listeners

Tags: java, javafx, togglebutton

I have 10 toggle buttons say tb1, tb2,.. and so on. Each one has one user data attached to it. I need to attach a listener for a action (sequence of instructions) to be performed when button are clicked and unclicked. I would prefer the listener to be generic (usable for all the buttons).

The problem I am facing is that, how can I access the user data of clicked button in the listener.Please help through this.

```
@FXML
private ToggleButton tb1;
@FXML
private ToggleButton tb2;

String cpuLoad1 ="D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/app_debug.apk";
String cpuLoad2 = "D:/myWorkspace/TestAttacks/input_folder/cpuLoad1.apk";


public void initialize(){

    tb1.setUserData(cpuLoad1);
    tb2.setUserData(cpuLoad2);
            
    ChangeListener clt1 = new ChangeListener() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov,
                Object toggle, Object new_toggle){
            if(new_toggle.equals(true)){
                                
                /*how can I acces togglebutton userdata here. 
                 *I would like to pass it as argument to this class object*/
                App load = new App(buttonClicked.getUserData());    //button clicked could tb1 or tb2
                load.installApp();
                load.launchApp();

            }else{
                System.out.println("OFF");
                /*how can I acces togglebutton userdata here. 
                 *I would like to pass it as argument to this class object.*/
                App load = new App(buttonClicked.getUserData());
                load.unInstallApp();
            }
        }
    };
    
    tb1.selectedProperty().addListener(clt1);

    tb2.selectedProperty().addListener(clt1);
    
}
```

Comment: Create [mcve] and show your problem.

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

**Option1:** Collect the `ToggleButton`s into a collection and use the reference directly in the listener:

```
List<ToggleButton> toggles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(tb1, tb2));

for(ToggleButton toggle:toggles)
    toggle.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
        System.out.println(toggle.getText() + " - Selected: " + toggle.isSelected() + "; UserData: " + toggle.getUserData()));
```

**Option2:** You can use the [`onActionProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#onActionProperty--):

```
tb1.setOnAction(e -> {
    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) e.getSource();
    System.out.println(toggle.getText() + " - Selected: " + toggle.isSelected()
            + "; UserData: " + toggle.getUserData());
});
```

---

**Option3:** If you need to store the listeners, you can implement you own `ChangeListener`.

```
public class Toggles extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton("ToggleButton" + i);
            tb.setUserData("UserData" + i);
            tb.selectedProperty().addListener(new ToggleButtonSourcedChangeListener(tb));
            vBox.getChildren().add(tb);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(vBox), 320, 240);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private abstract static class SourcedChangeListener<T extends Node> implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {
        T source;

        SourcedChangeListener(T source) {
            this.source = source;
        }
    }

    private static class ToggleButtonSourcedChangeListener extends SourcedChangeListener<ToggleButton> {

        ToggleButtonSourcedChangeListener(ToggleButton source) {
            super(source);
        }

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            System.out.println(source.getText() + " - Selected: " + source.isSelected()
                    + "; UserData: " + source.getUserData());
        }
    }
}
```

In this SSCE I created an abstract `SourceChangeListener` that can be extended by concrete implementations. The intention behind the generic parameter `<T extends Node>` is to avoid casts.

When you execute this code, and click on the toggles, the output will be like:

```
ToggleButton4 - Selected: true; UserData: UserData4
ToggleButton5 - Selected: true; UserData: UserData5
ToggleButton4 - Selected: false; UserData: UserData4
ToggleButton8 - Selected: true; UserData: UserData8
ToggleButton5 - Selected: false; UserData: UserData5
ToggleButton2 - Selected: true; UserData: UserData2
```

I would propose one of the options that use the `selectedProperty` as the `onActionProperty` will change only if the button was pressed (by mouse, touch or key) or if you programatically call the `fire()` method. The other two options will work always, even if you change the selected state programatically.

Comment: you dont need to keep a reference to the toggle - the selected property (as any other) has a field bean that's the owner of the property. And would strongly advise against the onAction, you already mentioned the why :-)